# Filtering in Powershell

Tags: powershell, filter

I have an array of objects called $listy.
I am looking for object for which property $_.WorkflowAssociations.Count is greater than 0.

When I select that property I can see that several objects fulfill my criteria:

```
$listy | select title, workflowassociations.count
```

However when I use where: `$listy | where {$_.WorkflowAssociations.Count -gt 0}` none of the objects are listed:
[image]

I have the same issue with $_.Views.Count property. Other numeric properties seem to filter without issues. Is it because of the point (.)? Why? The property is called exactly Views.Count:
[image]

Comment: Try `$_."WorkflowAssociations.Count"`?

Comment: Please post your terminal output as text (formatted as code) rather than screen captured image. It is quite a task to read through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EtanReisner already pointed out in the comments to your question: if you have a property name containing a dot (like `WorkflowAssociations.Count`) you *must* put the name in quotes when trying to access it via dot notation:

```psh
$listy | Where-Object { $_.'WorkflowAssociations.Count' -gt 0 }
```

If you don't, the term `$_.WorkflowAssociations.Count` will be interpreted as the property `Count` of a property `WorkflowAssociation` of the current object (`$_`). Which, of course, doesn't exist.